# PopupView from Vaadin Grid ButtonRender

Tags: java, image, blob, vaadin

so i think this may have something to do with the StreamSource but i can't quite track down the problem. Essentially i have a Vaadin Grid that retrieves it's data from a SQL database. The "Image" Column holds a BLOB value of the image that gets uploaded (successful method).

What i'm trying to do is allow the user to click on a button within the table and display that image in a popupview.

My ViewExpenses class:

```
aGrid.addColumn(reciept -> "Receipt", new ButtonRenderer<>(clickEvent ->{
        new ButtonRenderer<>(clickEvent ->{

                Window window = new Window();
                window.setModal(true);
                window.addCloseShortcut(ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ESCAPE, null);
                UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
                Expenses anExpense = aGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().stream().findFirst().get();
                long anID =  anExpense.getId();
                System.out.println(anID);
                StreamResource.StreamSource streamSource = (StreamResource.StreamSource)aController.getImage(anID);
                System.out.println("4");
                StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource(streamSource,"");
                Embedded embedded = new Embedded("",streamResource);
                System.out.println("5");
                Image anImage = new Image("Reciept", streamResource);
                window.setContent(anImage);
                anImage.setSizeFull();
                window.setSizeFull();

            })
    );
```

My backend DbController class method for getting the image:

```
 public InputStream getImage(long anIndex){
    InputStream binaryStream = null;
    try{Statement stmt = null;
        int intIndex = (int) anIndex;
        //connect to database
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.
                getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:Users", "sa", "");
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
        //insert data
        System.out.println("Getting expenses from the database...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM EXPENSES");
        Blob imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob(intIndex);
        binaryStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream(0, imageBlob.length());


    }


        catch (Exception e){

        }
        return binaryStream;
    }
```

I've been scratching my head with this for a while, i'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never displaying the `PopupView`. Then, when the button is clicked, the listener initializes a new `PopupView` but does nothing with it.

You can either:

1. Open a modal window when the button is clicked:

   ```
   Window window = new Window();
   window.setModal(true);
   window.addCloseShortcut(KeyCode.ESCAPE, null);
   UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
   Image anImage = ...
   window.setContent(anImage);
   anImage.setSizeFull();
   window.setSizeFull();
   ```
2. Use a [`ComponentRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/ComponentRenderer.html) that renders the `PopupView`.

   ```
   grid.addColumn(x->new PopupView(...))
     .setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer())
   ```

(Note that the use of component renderer can affect performance, the button renderer is lighter).

Comment: sweet so i've gone for the first option, 100% didn't realise you could do that with vaadin. I've amended the code above to reflect. However, i'm now getting a nullpointer exception from the handleConnectorRequest class. 

I suspect this is coming from the way i'm loading the image. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe... It's hard to tell where it fails without a stack trace, which by the way leads to a different question since your code has changed and now there is a different issue.

Comment: Same question as the image isn't displaying ;) hence the DBController code.